# How to toggle boolean in listview item independently?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, boolean

I am trying to change the color of a container with a button press.  It looks at the boolean value and determines the color.  How can I change the boolean for each individual listview item independently?

I am using provider for state management also.  This is just an example of the type of thing I am trying to do.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool colorToggle = false;

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: colorToggle ? Colors.blue : Colors.green,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  //how to change the colorToggle independendently with each listview item?
                  print('tapped');
                },
                child: Text('change color'),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check the link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994179/problem-switch-values-in-listview-flutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with with a single boolean value.

You can use a `List` instead. Add the index of the item to the `List` once an item is tapped. Then check the `List` for the item's index to set color

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List toggled = List();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: toggled.contains(i) ? Colors.blue : Colors.green,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  toggled.add(i);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: Text('change color'),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked!  Can you explain what List(); is? I know you are making a list called toggled in the example, but why isnt it 

List toggled = [];

Comment: List() means an Empty list. You can change it to []. that should also work